# React Axios Get method : Accessing key, value elements from the response

Tags: reactjs, rest, axios

I am getting successful response from axios get call but I cannot figure out to access individual key,value elements from the response. Please help

[image: JSON Data Response on Talend]

```
 componentDidMount()
    {
        axios.get('http://192.168.x.x:5000/xxx')
        .then((res)=>{

            console.log(res.data);
            const sensor = res.data;


        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are a minute away. Your code is absolutely correct all you need to do is to access the individual property and print their values like so.

```
componentDidMount()
    {
        axios.get('http://192.168.x.x:5000/xxx')
        .then((res)=>{
            console.log(res.data);
            const sensor = res.data;

            console.log(sensor.sensor_0) //will print the value for key sensor_0
            console.log(sensor.sensor_1) //will print the value for key sensor_1
            console.log(sensor.sensor_2)//will print the value for key sensor_2

        }).catch((error)=>console.log(error))
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
componentDidMount()
    {
        axios.get('http://192.168.x.x:5000/xxx')
        .then((res)=>{

           const {sensor_0, sensor_1, sensor_2} = res.data;
           console.log(sensor_0, sensor_1, sensor_2);

        })
    }
```

> we are destructuring the sensor_0, sensor_1 and sensor_2 values from the response

Answer (score 0):

The data is an object you can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to loop through an object.